# Get tag(term) name for multiple nodes without a performance hit

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, database

I want to get a list of nodes and return them as JSON along with their tags (names included). After a lot of research, I've only come up with this solution:

I have an array of Nodes (`\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface`) loaded with `Node::loadMultiple()`.

Iterating over the array of nodes, and getting their tags using `$node->field_tags` (or whatever the machine name of the tags is) which yields an array of `\Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\EntityReferenceItem`

Getting all the terms of the node using `Term::loadMultiple()` and then iterating over them and getting the name using `$term->name[0]->value`.

The problem is that there's an extra database read for every node, and I guess that the underlying query for this read is a JOIN :|.

**Question:** Is there an efficient way to load the tag (term) names along with `target_id`, `target_type`, `target_uuid`, etc? If no, is the current loop on each node the way to go???

**More Info:**

- I'm paginating the results
- The client can set the number of results per page, but there's a 50 nodes per page limit

Thanks

**P.S.**: I have two more types of tags so I have to do this two more times. Bright side is, the other two tags are 1to1.

Comment: You don't need `Term::loadMultiple()`, because you get the same result by applying `referencedEntities()` on the reference field. But this doesn't make a difference performance wise. For this the main tool in D8 is caching. Either in a cacheable response (add the cache tags of the nodes/terms and the node list tag to it) or if you have a lot of variations in the lists of nodes, then cache single nodes incl. the retrieved tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're already looping over an array of nodes, have you considered collecting the term IDs before loading them in one query? That should save a lot of the overhead of running multiple queries:

```
$map = [];
$tids = [];

// Collect IDs for each node:
/** @var \Drupal\node\Entity\NodeInterface[] $nodes */
foreach ($nodes as $nid => $node) {
  /** @var \Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\EntityReferenceItem $item */
  foreach ($node->field_tags as $item) {
    $tid = $item->target_id;
    $map[$nid][$tid] = $tid;
    $tids[$tid] = $tid;
  }
}

// Load terms and collect their labels:
$term_labels = [];
/** @var \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\TermInterface $term */
foreach (Term::loadMultiple($tids) as $tid => $term) {
  $term_labels[$tid] = $term->label();
}

// Assign the term labels to each node.
foreach ($map as $nid => $node_tids) {
  foreach ($node_tids as $tid) {
    $map[$nid][$tid] = $term_labels[$tid];
  }
}
```

Comment: The obvious thing is that this is far better than what I'm doing right now, so thanks. Although I can't help but wonder if it's possible to just load the `name` field along with the nodes.

Comment: No, it is not. But those loaded terms will be cached after you load them the first time